# Sequalize find latest created and updated_at

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, findall

I need to find the latest entry in a table. It should consider both the fields created_at and updated_at. If I add new data then it should come first or if I edit a then it should come first.

```
db.model.findAll({
  order: [ [ 'created_at ', 'DESC' ]]
}).then(function(data){
});
```

With the above code I can only list the entries based created_at how to combine both created_at  and updated_at ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the coalesce function in Postgres:

```
db.model.findAll({
  order: [ [ sequelize.fn('COALESCE', 'updated_at', 'created_at '), 'DESC' ]]
}).then(function(data){
});
```

The coalesce function checks if the first argument is null. If not, it returns it, else, it returns the second argument. If there is more than two arguments, the null checks chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.model.findAll({
      order: [
             [sequelize.literal('created_at, updated_at'), 'desc']
      ]
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Try like this

Comment: This will not bring the last modified record first, but the last created.